# No access to (nested) enum types (proto3) in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I was not able to access the (nested) enums in a trivial protocol buffer message. I tried either way, nested or separated from `DataNodeManagement`!:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message DataNodeManagement {
  string name = 1;
  string id = 2;
  string origin = 3;
  ConnectionType con_type = 4;
  enum ConnectionType {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    MQTT = 1;
  }
}
```

I am using this code to fill data in my message:

```
config = data_node_pb2.DataNodeManagement()
config.name = "Scanner1"
config.id = key
config.origin = "PC1"
config.con_type = data_node_pb2.ConnectionType.MQTT
# or 
# config.con_type = data_node_pb2.DataNodeManagement.ConnectionType.MQTT

datasource.advertise_data_node(config.SerializeToString())
```

And it complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner-connector.py", line 144, in <module>
    config.con_type = data_node_pb2.ConnectionType.MQTT
AttributeError: 'EnumTypeWrapper' object has no attribute 'MQTT'
```

respective:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner-connector.py", line 144, in <module>
    config.con_type = data_node_pb2.DataNodeManagement.ConnectionType.MQTT
AttributeError: type object 'DataNodeManagement' has no attribute 'ConnectionType'
```

I am using these versions:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1
```

Is there any special thing I overlooked as a beginner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to skip the enum-name to access the values from your enum. 
As can be seen in the [protocol-buffers python-tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#defining-your-protocol-format) the enum is defined within a message

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}
```

In the section [Reading a Message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#reading-a-message) the enum is accessed by

```
import addressbook_pb2
addressbook_pb2.Person.MOBILE
```

So in your example it should be `data_node_pb2.DataNodeManagement.MQTT`

Comment: Ironically, the place you linked to now uses the syntax `addressbook_pb2.Person.PhoneType.MOBILE` in their example code.  However, it has the syntax `addressbook_pb2.Person.HOME` up higher. Furthermore, only the latter works for me, about which I may open a separate question.

Comment: Follow-up, both should work, see [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6028) for discussion.